# CURRENT_ARCH not expanding correctly?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have an Xcode project (Xcode 6.3.1) with the following library search paths set:

"$(SRCROOT)/Libraries/ScaleformLib/${CURRENT_ARCH}/clang/${CONFIGURATION}_NoRTTI"
"$(SRCROOT)/Libraries/ScaleformLib/${CURRENT_ARCH}/clang/"

When building I get linker errors, which seem to be due to the CURRENT_ARCH variable not expanding correctly (paths shortened/removed for clarity):

```
Ld Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/mud normal armv7
cd builds/iOSSubmission
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
clang++ -arch armv7 -isysroot
-L/builds/iOSSubmission/Libraries/ScaleformLib/arm64/clang/Release_NoRTTI
-L/builds/iOSSubmission/Libraries/ScaleformLib/arm64/clang
```

I'm unsure why arm64 is being inserted into the search paths when it seems like it should be armv7? What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem - also with Scaleform. Please post the solution if you found one

Answer (score 3):

Original answer was wrong but this one works.

So for us, it came down to header search path for a .dylib.  We needed libxml2 so we had header search path set to

> /usr/include/libxml2

This isn't SDK dependent (shouldn't the dylib actually link to the SDK we're using?) so we changed it to:

> $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2

And everything was fine.